# Extract Sqlite Database using Chrome DevTools (Stetho)

Tags: android, google-chrome-devtools, stetho

I am using [Stetho](https://github.com/facebook/stetho) as debug bridge for my Android apps. Through this I can "inspect" and open Chrome DevTools attached to my app. I can access my app's local database under Resources->Web SQL->"MyApplication.db". I was wondering:

Is there a way, using DevTools, to extract "MyApplication.db" or "Save As..." another file so I can open it in other database browsers (e.g. SQLiteDatabaseBrowserPortable)?

Answer (score 0):

Yes, you can extract your Database file from Android Studio.

Steps:

1. Go to Device file Explorer -> select data folder
2. Inside data select data folder again.
3. choose your package name.
4. select database folder from inside and right click on your database file click save as.

   [image]

Comment: this really works for extracting the android chrome app db but I was asking about stetho and devTools, not android studio. anyway, thank you for answering

Comment: @aLL, with devTools you can only check top 250 DB entries.